# how can I easily get the two biggest elements of an array?

Tags: list, haskell, max

It's not a difficult problem, but I'm not able to find a solution for it without writing 5 lines or more.

I want the definition of the following function:

```hs
-- takes a list and give back the 2 biggest elements
getTwoBiggest :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
```

### Edit

I could do it by sorting and taking the 2 first elements, but I don't find a clear documentation for sorting a list in descending order.

How can I do it ?
What is the connection with the type `Down` ?

Comment: Haskell's sort is lazy, so if *k* is fixed, you get the first *k* elements in *O(n)*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem are you sure it doesn't depend on the sort ? Any way how can I sort my list in decreasing order ?

Comment: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy

Comment: You can use `map (\(Down a) -> a) . sort . map Down`. If you compile with optimizations enabled, this should produce exactly the same binary code you'd get with `sortBy`.

Comment: `getDown :: Down a -> a` is already defined.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list sorted in reverse order, you should make use of `sortBy` and and `Down`.

if you don't know them, you can find their documentation easily via hoogle:

https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=Down

https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=sortBy

`sortBy` lets you specify a custom comparison function.

`Down` is a newtype wrapper to reverse the sort order - specified by an Ord instance - of the type that it wraps.

Putting those together with a bit of error handling will give you:

```
import Data.Ord
import Data.List

getTwoBiggest :: [Int] -> (Int, Int)
getTwoBiggest xs | (x:y:_) <- reverseSort xs = (x,y)
                 | otherwise = undefined -- hande lists with less than two elements
    where reverseSort = sortBy (comparing Down)
```